# How to create a circle like this using QPaint

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create something like this

[image]

This is my approach

```
QPixmap target(60,80);            
QBrush BackGroundBrush;
BackGroundBrush.setColor(QColor(Qt::GlobalColor::black));
QPainter painter(&target);
painter.setBackground(BackGroundBrush);
painter.drawEllipse(10,10,10,10);
```

Now I wanted to know how I could fill it completely with color ? I was then thinking of painting another circle(white) inside this circle?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `painter.setPen` to choose what color and style you will be drawing boundaries with and `painter.setBrush` to set color and style of what you will be filling it with. Basically to fill something with solid color without boundaries you have to use simply:

```
painter.setPen (Qt::NoPen);
painter.setBrush (colorOfYourLiking);
```

About `setBackground` there's following lines in Qt documentation:

> Sets the background brush of the painter to the given brush.
>
> The background brush is the brush that is filled in when drawing opaque text, stippled lines and bitmaps.

I guess this is not what you need.

Comment: Now I cant see the circle

Comment: @MistyD If you want to see boundary of circle use `painter.setPen (yourColor)` or do not set it at all then you will get black boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing the following

```
BackGroundBrush->setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern)
```